# calculate the new direction if reflected vector in 3d space with python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, 3d

i have a cell that has a normal vector after my incident beam hit the cell i calculate the angle between the normal and incident beam and angle was 45 degree now i want to calculate the new direction of reflected ray after hitting with rotation matrix but i am stuck with doing it
i have the normal like this(not constant) for example (1,0,1) and the direction like this(0,0,-1)
how i should calculate the rotation matrix and give me 3 new direction and along which axis should i do rotation ?

```
def angle_between(v1, v2):
    v1_u = -unit_vector(v1)
    v2_u = unit_vector(v2)
    gradian = np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(v1_u, v2_u), -1.0, 1.0))
    return gradian
```

and this my main cal_rotaion

```
def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    print(np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac)],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab)],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc]])
)
    return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac)],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab)],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc]])

v = [0,0,-1]
axis = [1,0,1]
theta = np.deg2rad(45)

print(np.dot(rotation_matrix(axis, theta), v))
```

what result should i expect? and how i can  check the validity of function(if you think is right)

Answer (score 2):

You CAN'T use a rotation matrix to do a reflection. You CAN use a general transformation matrix (whose elements are given at the bottom of this post). However, it is NOT a rotation matrix: its determinant is -1.

Instead, you can easily avoid matrix transformations altogether. Split the incident vector into parts `vn` and `vt` which are parallel to and perpendicular to the normal, respectively. If `n` is a unit normal, then

`vn = (v.n)n`

`vt = v - vn`

After reflection, the part parallel to the normal would have its sign reversed and the plane-tangential part would be unchanged. Reassemble the new vector:

`vreflected = vt - vn`

which you will notice is just

`vreflected = v - 2 vn = v - 2(v.n)n`

In terms of checking it ... well for your example I used a sheet of paper and a couple of pencils, which I waved in the air.

```
import numpy as np

def reflect_vector( v, normal ):
    n = normal / np.linalg.norm( normal )
    return v - 2 * v.dot( n ) * n

v = np.array( [ 0.0, 0.0, -1.0 ] )
normal = np.array( [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ] )

print( "Original vector = ", v )
print( "Reflected vector = ", reflect_vector( v, normal ) )
```

Output (subject to some floating-point round-off):

```
Original vector =  [ 0.  0. -1.]
Reflected vector =  [ 1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -2.22044605e-16]
```

If you absolutely have to do it by a matrix transformation (and I definitely don't advise this) then the transformation matrix just has (i,j) component `delta_ij - 2 n_i n_j`, where `delta_ij` is the Kronecker delta.

Comment: thank you for solution.but why should not using rotation matrix ? and could you please guide more how can i apply that rotation matrix?

Comment: @sina jamshidi, if you want to do it by a matrix transformation then the components of that matrix are given at the end of my post: `delta_ij - 2 n_i n_j`. However, as I write in that answer, that would be a much more computationally-intensive way of doing it. Also, if you try to find a rotation axis when the vector approaches along the (negative) normal then the rotation axis would be ambiguous (it could be anything in the reflecting plane).

Comment: Also, a reflection is NOT a rotation - it will have determinant -1.